# How do the puts and gets functions work?

Tags: c, scanf, gets, puts

```
main()
{
char name[20];

printf("enter your name\n");

scanf("%s",name);       
printf("%s",name);

gets(name);
puts(name);
}
```

> input:  Sampad Saha

Output

> Sampad Saha

Here puts only uses the input taken from `gets()`.

as, if I omit this `printf()` the output would be

> Saha

So here puts does not print anything given through `scanf()`.

```
main()
{
char color[20];

printf("enter your name\n");

scanf("%s",color);   
puts(color);
}
```

But here `puts()` uses the input taken from `scanf()` also.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is, for an input like

> abc XYZ

the code

```
  scanf("%s",name);
```

reads *only* the "abc" part and the "XYZ" is left in the input buffer. The later `gets()` read that, and `puts()` prints that. As you don't have a `newline` after the `printf()`, the output is not *flushed* and the outcome of the `puts()` is *appended* to the output stream buffer and once the program finishes execution, the whole output buffer is flushed altogether printing the *whole* input together.

So, in the other case, when you drop the `printf()`, the value read by `scanf()` (*"abc"*)is not printed.

To elaborate, `%s` with `scanf()` cannot read whitespace delimited inputs, it stops the reading at the first whitespace encountered.

Quoting `C11`. chapter §7.21.6.2

> `s`     Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters. [...]

which indicates, for `%s`, `scanf()` stops reading upon encountering first whitespace.

Coming to the second case, where the input does not *contain* a whitespace, (i.e., not a whitespace-separated input is given), `scanf()` reads the *whole* input (upto terminating newline) and thus, both the `printf()` and `puts()` outputs the same.

That said, [DO NOT use `gets()`, it is dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2173917). use [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.

Comment: I dont know if I am wrong or right..but isn't the print omition case (2nd example) printing the Saha only because same variable is being used in that case? And in first case it is stored in output buffer before it  gets lost by reading from` gets()` Third case is obvious..

Comment: @coderredoc Right, as long as the `pf/sf` and `gets/puts` pair uses the same variable, it will be the same. the variable _between_ the pair may change but not the result. :)