# Confusing sequence of Code flow on Cygwin

Tags: c, cygwin

There is this exceptionally simple program in C (built with gcc on Cygwin)::

```
// This program is a tutorial to Stack-based overflow, that's why "gets"
    #include <stdio.h>

    void test()
    {
        char buff[4];
        printf("Some input: ");
        gets(buff);
        puts(buff);
    }

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        test();
        return 0;
    }
```

Now when I run this on Windows console,`printf` executes first and waits for the input::
[image]

But when I run the same exe under Cygwin terminal, it waits for the input and then `printf` executes::

[image]

Why is this difference?

EDIT:: With `\n` appended to the string in `printf` statement, the behaviour remains the same::

[image]

Comment: `printf("Some input: "); --> printf("Some input: ");fflush(stdout);`

Comment: The interworking of output to stdout (screen) without a newline at the end (the prompt) and the input from stdin (keyboard) is a delicate topic.  It appears that the Windows and Cygwin libraries have different views on what happens.  You can force the output with `fflush(stdout)`.   Note that your order of presentation is not convincing; the second screen shows a recompilation of `testbuff.exe`, so to be a valid assertion, you'd have to have generated the second screen image first and the first image second.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - The sequencing of images is ordered to make my doubt clear to the SO community. I assure you that the exe executed on both consoles are exactly same :)

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya - I figured that out but what I would like to know is the reason behind it. +1 for the comment though :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Do you mean that if I put a newline char in the `printf` statement, the behavior might change?

Comment: [___DO NOT___ use `gets()`, even if for casual code, it is dangerous. use `fgets()` instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41383540/2173917)

Comment: Yes; it would change.  (The behaviour would change if you added a newline to the `printf()` output.)

Comment: @SouravGhosh - Thanks for the warning. I am trying to figure out a Stack-based overflow exploit :)

Comment: stdin and stdout are by default line buffered, AFAIR.

Comment: The input and output streams usually have a buffering character. Some implementation of libc use line buffering while some use character buffering. The code for `printf` (actually `__vfprintf` for windows) is usually dynamically linked. So Cygwin and cmd might be using different versions of the dll and hence you are seeing different behavior. Although, waiting for input should usually flush `stdout`. Also how the contents of `stdin` and `stdout` are interleaved is dependent of the terminal implementation.

Comment: Please do not add text output as graphics. That's no artwork,

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I did try with the newline char, yet the behaviour remains the same. I have edited the question to include that too.

Comment: That's surprising to me; I don't have a good answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - That's surprising to me that "you" don't have a good answer :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some reading and research, I concluded at a final theory for this behaviour.

**Short Answer::** `stdout` is buffered, so doing a

```
void test()
{
    char buff[4];
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0); // <--- setting stdout to _IONBF
    printf("Some input: ");
    gets(buff);
    puts(buff);
}
```

before printing anything to console or,

```
void test()
    {
        char buff[4];
        printf("Some input: ");
        fflush(stdout); // <--- force the stdout to flush
        gets(buff);
        puts(buff);
    }
```

after the `printf` statement will solve the issue.

**Long Answer::**

When I run the same exe with `Bash.exe`, the stdout is not buffered::
[image]

And the same exe with `mintty.exe`, the stdout is buffered::
[image]

Now the question is,

- why `stdout` is unbuffered in one and buffered on another?

> As you can see the `tty` output on both, bash shows as console session
>   `/dev/cons0`, whereas the mintty shows as pseudo-terminal session
>   `/dev/pty0`.

So,

- how does it answer the question of unbuffered and buffered stdout?

> My browsing re-re-and-re searches landed me [here](http://www.aps.anl.gov/epics/tech-talk/2014/msg00149.php), stating, **If I type `tty`
>   in the respective Cygwin windows, I see that `mintty` and `xterm` are both
>   pseudo-terminals whereas `bash` is a console session - I believe
>   `procServ` uses `forkpty()`. So I think it boils down to Windows treating
>   a Cygwin pty as non-interactive and thus buffering both `stdout` and
>   `stderr`.**

I am not sure, how precise this is but yes, this seems to be a practical and best explanation of this behaviour.

According to `Section 7.9.13/7 of c99` states that:

> At program start-up, three text streams are predefined and need not be
>   opened explicitly - standard input (for reading conventional input),
>   standard output (for writing conventional output), and standard error
>   (for writing diagnostic output).
>
> As initially opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered;
>   **the standard input and standard output streams are fully buffered if
>   and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an
>   interactive device**.

<sub>*The bold emphasis is mine.</sub>

Comment: Windows CMD knows nothing of pty's. Mintty is fully aware.

Comment: @matzeri - Any other theory for this behaviour?