# Could not get the entered string from the stack of function

Tags: c, pass-by-value, function-call

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

static void get_string(char *ac)
{
    ac = (char *)malloc (1 * sizeof (char));
    printf("Enter the string to count vowels and consonants in a string using pointers: ");
    scanf("%s", ac);
}

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *ac = NULL;
    get_string(ac);
    printf("The Entered string is:%s", ac);
    for(;;);
}
```

Could not get the entered string from the stack of function. Returns null.Can anyone help me in debug?

Comment: If you allocate space for only **1** character, what string do you expect to get exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Function arguments in C is passed by value. Any changes made to the parameters from inside the called function will not reflect to the actual argument supplied at function call.

In your case, you *wanted* to change `ac` itself (not the content of the memory location it points to), so, that would need a pointer-to-`ac`.

That said,

- [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of malloc() and family in C..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)
- `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1 in C, no need to use it as multiplier
- a memory allocation of 1 byte can only hold an empty string, that's probably meaningless (and erroneous) in your code.

Comment: Then what are the modification I need to do in the code?

Comment: Mallocate a sane length for your input, (256, say), use a width of [length-1] in your scanf() format string, and then either return the string from get_string() as a char* or use a double-pointer argument/parameter to allow the allocated pointer to be communicated back to the caller.  Easiest to just return it.

Comment: Oh - and free() the char* after printffing it in main().

Comment: ..or change your design so that main() allocates the string space and 'get_string()' loads it up.  Should probably pass in the string pointer and a max length in that case.

Comment: @MartinJames I'd second the last idea, cleanest, IMHO.

Comment: I dont want to return anything to main.I wanted to change in the stack of main memory itself

Comment: https://ideone.com/uEQpqA

Comment: Hope this will work!!

Comment: @jiju [___DO NOT___ use `gets()`, it is dangerous. use `fgets()` instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41383540/2173917)

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh Thanks sourav!!Can I know why?

Comment: @jiju That's there in the link...