# array of pointers to string characters

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

*when input is given five ,instead of asking for 5 string it takes only four ,Why is it so ?*
*why by default `*a+0 = '\n'` is saved ?*
*I have also tried `scanf("%d %c", &n &ch )` at line 9,but the problem was same.*

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

int main()
    {
        int n;
        char ch;
        printf("no of elements\n");
        scanf("%d ", &n ); //line 9
        //asking for number of pointer in array 
        char *a[n];
        puts("string");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
            gets(a+i);
        }
        puts("-----");
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j){
            puts(a+j);
        }
        puts("-----");
        puts(a);
        puts("-----");
        puts(a+2);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: [___DO NOT___ use `gets()`, it is dangerous. use `fgets()` instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41383540/2173917)

Comment: You have undefined behavior because the pointers in `a` aren't pointing anywhere.

Comment: @Kevin But how is it so ,Please explain properly

Comment: @kelvin But if a is not pointing any where then ,How a+i is pointing some where else (1<i<any intezer)

Comment: `char *a[n]` defines an array of `n` pointers to `char`. But those pointers are uninitialized and don't point to valid memory. You need to assign them to something (i.e. `a[i] = ...`) before you can write something to the memory they point to.

Comment: Can't reproduce... Are you sure that your code is `scanf("%d ", &n );` ? Your description sounds as if your code is `scanf("%d", &n );`, i.e. without the space after `%d`

Comment: @4386427 it doesn't matters ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

The declared variable in this declaration

```
char ch;
```

is not used in the program and should be removed.

And neither declaration from the header `<string.h>` is used in your program. So the header could be removed.

You declared a variable length array of pointers to the type `char`

```
char *a[n];
```

However the elements of the array were not initialized and have indeterminate values. As result the program has undefined behavior due to this statement in the for loop

```
gets(a+i);
```

You have to allocate memory for each string you are going to enter.

Also take into account that the function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported any more by the C Standard. Instead use the function `fgets`. Moreover the argument in the function call must be `*( a + i )` instead of `a + i` because the type of the last expression is `char **` instead of the required type `char *`.

So a valid code can look for example the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    size_t n;
    const size_t SIZE = 20;

    printf( "no of elements: " );

    if ( scanf( "%zu%*c", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) n = 1;

    char * a[n];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        *( a + i ) = malloc( SIZE );    
    }

    puts("string");

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i )
    {
        fgets( *( a + i ), SIZE, stdin );
    }

    puts("-----");

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i )
    {
        printf( "%s", *( a + i ) );
    }

    puts( "-----" );
    printf( "%s", *a );

    puts( "-----" );
    printf( "%s", *( a + 2 ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        free( *( a + i ) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
no of elements: 5
string
A
B
C
D
E
-----

A
B
C
D
E
-----
A
-----
C
```

Pay attention to this statement

```
    if ( scanf( "%zu%*c", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) n = 1;
```

After reading the variable `n` using format specifier `&zu` you need to remove from the input buffer the new line character  that corresponds to the pressed key Enter. Otherwise the next call of `fgets` will read an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int n;
  printf("no of elements\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);  // No space after the %d !

  char dummy[2];            // these 2 lines are needed for absorbing the leftover
  fgets(dummy, 2, stdin);  // \n from scanf (mixing fgets and scanf is a bad idea)

  char *a[n];       // here we'll have an array of n pointers to char. For the moment
                    // the array is not initialized and the pointers point nowhere

  puts("string");

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    a[i] = malloc(100);         // allocate memory for a string of a maximum length of 99.
                                // + one char for the NUL terminator
                                // Allocating a fixed size is awkward, but it will
                                // do here for demonstration purposes

    fgets(a[i], 100, stdin);    // limit the length of string to 100 in order
                                // to avoid buffer overflow
                                // it's basically the same as gets(buffer)
  }

  puts("-----");
  for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
    puts(a[j]);
  }

  puts("-----");
  puts(a[0]);
  puts("-----");
  puts(a[2]);

  return 0;
}
```

Input and output:

```
no of elements
3
string
11
22
33
-----
11

22

33

-----
11

-----
33
```

Error checking is avoided for brevity.