# Why does it print that my list is empty?

Tags: c, function, struct, linked-list

I have an add function and use a realloc to take in the data from a struct and store it. But when I print it out, it says that it's empty, which comes from my display function. How can I fix this?

```
void additem(food *head, int index) {
    head = (food*)realloc(head, sizeof(food)*(index + 1));
    if (head != NULL) {
        printf("Enter name: ");
        gets((head + index)->name);
        printf("Type unit of meauserement: ");
        gets((head + index)->unit);
        printf("Enter value: ");
        scanf("%d", &(head + index)->data);
    }
    else {
        printf("\nExiting!!");
        free(head);
    }
}
```

My main function looks like this:

```
food *foods = NULL;
int option, nofood = 0;
while (1) {
    system("CLS");
    printf("1 - add food\n2 - print shopping list\n3 - delete item\n4 - change amount\n5 - end\nWhat do you want to do? ");
    scanf("%d", &option);
    clear();
    switch (option) {
    case 1: additem(foods, nofood);
        break;
```

Comment: [___DO NOT___ use `gets()`, it is dangerous. use `fgets()` instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41383540/2173917)

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of malloc() and family in C..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Comment: You know what? Outside the function, `head` remains unchanged!!

Comment: Also `noFood` never changes resulting in `index` within `additem` being 0 forever.

Comment: @SouravGhosh This doesn't help because this is exactly what was asked. Be more constructive.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès What does not help??

Comment: @Adrian  Kindly show your research / debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: "which comes from my display function" Why don't you even show your display function? I assume it does not come from this function but from passing parameters by value instead of reference.

Comment: My display function looks like this: pastebin.com/WjEfCHgH @Gerhardh

Comment: @SouravGhosh Your comment.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Which part?

Answer (score 1):

The updated value of `head` is never returned to the caller. Use:

```
void additem(food **head, int index) {

    *head = (food*)realloc(*head, sizeof(food)*(index + 1));
```

and call it like:

```
    additem(&foods, nofood);
```

When you pass `food` you pass the value of `food`. Although the function updates this value, the value is not communicated back to the caller. This is called "call-by-value". If you pass the *address* of `food`, and assign to the thing (variable) that `head` points to, you have changed the caller's value. This is called "call-by-reference" (though strictly speaking, passing any pointer is call-by-reference).

Comment: I did that, and I wrote the get function like this: gets((*head + index)->name); etc. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: That is because you have to increment `nofood` too.

Comment: Okay, but I can't get past the realloc function because a breakpoint gets triggered.

Comment: Use a debugger to check what you do wrong. I can't see what you did exactly. And increment `nofood` _after_ calling `additem`, of course.

Comment: I made it work, and I added a noFood++; in main after calling additem ofcourse, but it still prints that the list is empty from my display function.

Comment: Now it prints the list, and I can add several items, but it breaks on my print within my display function.

Comment: Show your print function.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this simple program:

```
void foo(int bar)
{
  bar = bar + 1;
}

int main()
{
  int test = 4;
  foo(bar);
  printf("bar = %d\n", bar);
}
```

What is the output of this simple program?
If you know the answer you know the answer to your problem.