# reverse string in c incorrect output

Tags: c, string

I was writing a program to reverse an entered string in C and my code is :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
    int sz;
    printf("Enter the size of the string : ");
    scanf("%d",&sz);
    char str[sz];
    gets(str);
    printf("Enter the string : \n");
    gets(str);
    char str1[sz];
    int i =0;
    --sz;
    for(i=0;i<=sz;i++)    
    {
          str1[sz-i]=str[i];

    }
    printf("%s",str1);
}
```

well this program is giving an weird output for string sizes 8,9 and 10
for size 8 the reversed string is being printed followed by a space and 2 garbage characters,for size 9 the reversed string is being printed followed by 2 garbage characters and for size 10 the reversed string is being printed by a garbage character and for other string sizes the program is running properly. why is this happening?

Comment: There is no `gets` in C. Use `fgets(str, sz - 1, c)`

Comment: You didn't null-terminate `str1`.

Comment: @NO you realize that what you're saying is incorrect?

Comment: @Antti Haapala Yeah I didn't null terminate them but why are these garbage characters being displayed only for string sizes 8,9and 10 why not for other string sizes also

Comment: because you didn't null-terminate. The behaviour is undefined then.

Comment: Yeah I haven't null terminated it and that is true for string sizes less than 8 or more than 10 but why is the error occurring only for 8,9 and 10 and not for any other string size?

Comment: Do you need to store the reverse string in memory ? And although you can use variable sized array, you should consider how they would behave if `sz` is quite large, check where the string is terminating as you should not trust what the user is putting as input. I would recommend to overallocate the first string then use strlen to get en end of the string.

Comment: I don't understand one thing - you wish to reverse **one** string by your code. Then why do you have two `gets()` statements in your code?

Comment: [___DO NOT___ use `gets()`, it is dangerous. use `fgets()` instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41383540/2173917)

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**

- It is not smart to try to limit the input string by asking the user, the user can still write string with length greater/ less
- Reading string from console does by default not allow spaces

**First option:**
Read a string of a static size:

```
 char original[5];
 scanf("%5s", original); // String containing 5 chars
```

**Second option:**
Read a string of variable size:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Length of String
unsigned expected;

printf("Enter the length of the string: ");
scanf("%u", &expected);

char *temp; // Warning: Uninitialized

// Get string
printf("Enter the string: ");
scanf("%s", temp);

unsigned actual = strlen(temp);
unsigned length = actual > expected ? expected : actual;

char *string = (char *) malloc(length * sizeof(char));
char *reverse = (char *) malloc(length * sizeof(char));

 // Trim string to proper size
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  string[i] = temp[i];
}

// Reverse string
for (int i = 0, j = length - 1; i <= j; i++) {
  reverse[i] = string[j - i];
}

// Print Strings
printf("%s", string);
printf("\n%s", reverse);
```