# Initialized variable skips 0 during for loop

Tags: c

This is a simple version of my code that still doesn't work when I run it. When I initialize `i` to be the counter for my `for` loop, it skips `0` for some reason, this has never happened to me before and I don't know why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int x, i;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    char array[x][10];
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        gets(array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

edit: I input 5 for `x`, therefore I would have a character array size 5 rows, 10 columns. For `i`, it is supposed to start at 0, so I input `array[0]` first but skips to 1, so I start my input with `array[1]`, that means my first row has no input.

Comment: [___DO NOT___ use `gets()`, it is dangerous. use `fgets()` instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41383540/2173917)

Comment: How would you say that 0 is skipped? What is the expected behavior, what is the observed behavior?

Comment: If you use the C tag, it is assumed that you program in standard C. But this code cannot compile as standard C because it is too old. Therefore you need to add an extra tag corresponding to the dinosaur version of C that you are for some reason using, such as C90 or C99.

Comment: Also make sure to burn the book or teacher that told you to use gets, then get a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf()` leaves some characters in the input stream, which are picked up by the first call to `gets()`, causing the first `gets()` to finish immediately and the program to continue and prompt for the input for `array[1]`, hence "skipping" over `0`.

Comment: How do I prevent that? I used fgets() and the result is the same.

Comment: You could add an extra `fgets()` prior to the loop to drain the input stream, or possibly just continue to use `scanf()` instead, if all you want to do is get one integer at a time.

Comment: @Hele try fflush(stdin);

Comment: @EmreAcar `fflush(stdin)` is UB.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf()` only consumes the characters that make up the converted number.  Any remaining input, especially the newline that you typed after `5` is left in the input stream.

The `for` loop does start at `0`, and `0` must be output by your program, but `gets()` reads the pending input upto and including the newline, so the next iteration comes immediately: `1` is output and the program only then waits for input.

Note that you must not use obsolete function `gets()` because it cannot determine the maximum number of characters to store to the destination array, so undefined behavior on invalid input cannot be avoided.  Use `fgets()` or `getchar()` instead.

Here is how to fix your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int x, i, j, c;
    if (scanf("%d", &x) != 1)
        return 1;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;
    char array[x][10];
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        for (j = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n';) {
            if (j < 9)
                array[i][j++] = c;
        }
        array[i][j] = '\0';
    }
    return 0;
}
```